# Question on the difference between harmonic series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory, harmonic-numbers

I found the following identity:

For $r>s>0$ and integers.
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m+r} \frac{1}{m+s} = \frac{H_r-H_s}{r-s} = \frac{1}{r-s} \left( \frac{1}{s+1} + \frac{1}{s+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r}\right)
\end{align}
For $r>s>0$ and both $r,s$ odd integers.
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2m+r} \frac{1}{2m+s} = \frac{H_{r/2}-H_{s/2}}{2(r-s)} = \:\: ?
\end{align}

What is the difference between $H_{r/2}-H_{s/2} \:\:?$

EDIT: 
I think the correct answer is:
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2m+r} \frac{1}{2m+s} = \frac{1}{r-s} 
\left( \frac{1}{s+2} + \frac{1}{s+4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r} \right)
\end{align}

Comment: For $s > r$ odds $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2m+r} \frac{1}{2m+s} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} 
 \frac{1}{s-r} (\frac{1}{2m+r} -\frac{1}{2m+s})= \frac{1}{s-r} \sum_{n=0}^{(s-r)/2-1}\frac{1}{r+2n}$ $= \frac{1}{s-r} ( H_{s+1}- \frac12H_{(s+1)/2}-(H_{r+1}- \frac12 H_{(r+1)/2}))$

Comment: $m$ starts at $1$. I wanted to write $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2m+r} \frac{1}{2m+s} $ in a way that doesn't use the $H_n$ notation, just like the first sum. Instead of $\frac{H_r-H_s}{r-s}$ we write $ \frac{1}{r-s} \left( \frac{1}{s+1} + \frac{1}{s+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r}\right)$

Comment: To calculate the difference $H_\frac{r}{2} - H_\frac{s}{2}$ for $r\gt s$ use the identity $H_{x} = H_{x-1}+\frac{1}{x}$